# Leaflet.markercluster Gives slow performance when zooming

Tags: leaflet, markers

I have used [leaflet marker cluster](https://github.com/Leaflet/Leaflet.markercluster) to render the geojson.

I am rendering 1 million geojson data. This gives better performance when render the data, but when zooming the map, gives very slow performance.

How to avoid this issue?

I am using the events `zoomstart` and `zoomend` to show the spinner.

Even zoomstart starts only after 2 or 3 seconds.
This is starting after 6 or 8 seconds.

```
 map.on("zoomstart", function (e) {map.spin(true);});
 map.on("zoomend", function (e) { map.spin(false); });
```

Answer (score 1):

Use a different [clustering plugin](http://leafletjs.com/plugins.html#clusteringdecluttering).

There are 10 listed for clustering/decluttering.

Comment: This is the same plugin I am using. But zooming gives worst performance